# Not getting expected results from SQLITE query

Tags: sqlite, join, select, where-clause, inner-join

I'm struggling to get the right result back from a LEFT JOIN with a WHERE clause with SQLITE. I have two tables - contents and actions.

I want a return of all actions where the content creation date is between a date A and date B. However, when I add the WHERE clause, i'm only getting the first action for each content item. When I remove the WHERE clause, I get all actions as expected.

Below is a simplified example of the tables:

Contents:

| content_id | creation_date | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | A |
| 2 | 2022-12-11 | B |
| 3 | 2022-12-31 | C |
| 4 | 2023-01-07 | D |
| 5 | 2023-01-22 | E |

Actions:

| action_id | Action | content_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CLICK | 2 |
| 2 | CLICK | 1 |
| 3 | SEND | 1 |
| 4 | SEND | 1 |
| 5 | CLICK | 3 |
| 6 | SEND | 4 |
| 7 | SEND | 4 |
| 8 | CLICK | 3 |
| 9 | CLICK | 5 |

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
c.content_id,
c.creation_date,
c.content,
a.action_id
a.action
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN actions a ON a.content_id = c.content_id
WHERE c.creation_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-30'
GROUP BY a.action_id
```

I expected to see a result like:

| content_id | creation_date | content. | action_id | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | A | 2 | CLICK |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | A | 3 | SEND |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | A | 4 | SEND |
| 4 | 2023-01-07 | D | 6 | SEND |
| 4 | 2023-01-07 | D | 7 | SEND |
| 5 | 2023-01-22 | E | 9 | CLICK |

The result I get is the first action for each content where creation date is between the range rather than each action associated with content created within the range. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data what you need is just an `INNER` join without any aggregation:

```
SELECT c.content_id, c.creation_date, c.content,
       a.action_id, a.action
FROM content c INNER JOIN actions a 
ON a.content_id = c.content_id
WHERE c.creation_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-30';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UlQbVtdE).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I ran it with INNER JOIN first but the response was 0 rows. Tried that again with the same result. I'm thinking there's an issue in the DB itself at this stage so I might try rebuild it. Cant's see what it would be though. There are 28 content items created during that date range and each has over 1000 actions.

Comment: @BillDukelow you can see in the demo link that the query works as expected. Also, in your question you mention that your query even without returning correct results it does return rows, so I guess you are not using my query as it is. Create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_) with sample data where you reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to but it's failing on the FK assignment for the second table. I'll try figure it out.

Comment: created it again in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RZZk7YEf) with FK constraints and it works as expected. It's obviously something strange happening with the DB. I'll mark this as the correct answer as it's correct. Any ideas why I might be seeing this behaviour?

Comment: @BillDukelow In your question you say "when I add the WHERE clause, i'm only getting the first action for each content item" which means that you get something, right? Removing GROUP BY should result in more rows and not an empty resultset, since there are matches in the joins.

Comment: That's what I would have thought. When I remove the WHERE clause, I get the expected results set of 61K (All actions). When I add the WHERE clause with a LEFT JOIN I get 28 results (the same number of content items for that range). When I do an INNER JOIN with the WHERE clause I get 0 results. It's puzzling.

Comment: @BillDukelow do these 28 rows contain matching rows from `actions` or not?

Comment: They do. Every single content item has at least one action, but usually 1000's. With that query, it appears to just return the first action for each content item. I can run something like `SELECT COUNT(action_id) FROM actions WHERE content_id = '357947'` for a content item that falls within the range for example and i'll get the count of what I expect. But when joining content and actions, I don't get the expected result with either no results or 28 being returned.

Comment: @BillDukelow if you get matching rows and you only need matching rows then the INNER join is the way to do it. Also, if the sample data in the fiddle link of one of your previous comments is part of your actual data then it is obvious that there is a problem with the integrity of the database. Try to export it and recreate it.

Comment: It seems like it was the integrity of the DB. I recreated it from the seed data and i'm getting the expected results now.

Comment: @BillDukelow fine if it is solved.